# Is there a way to select one column from a Dynamic SQL statement that falls within particular boundaries

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

SQL Server:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test_Pagination_Proc]
    @DBNAME nvarchar(200),
    @STOREDPROC nvarchar(200),
    @INDEX int,
    @PageSize int
/*
    DECLARE @DBNAME nvarchar(200) = 'C110_victoribasco18_gmail'
            ,@STOREDPROC nvarchar(200) = 'Friends_Pagination'
            ,@INDEX int = 1
            ,@PageSize int = 4

    EXEC [dbo].[Test_Pagination_Proc]
                                @DBNAME,
                                @STOREDPROC,
                                @INDEX,
                                @PageSize

*/
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL_QUERY nvarchar(4000) = N'EXEC ' + QUOTENAME(@DBName) + N'.dbo.' + QUOTENAME(@STOREDPROC) + N'@INDEX, @PageSize ';

    CREATE TABLE #T1 
    (
        Id int, 
        Title nvarchar(120), 
        Bio nvarchar(700), 
        Summary nvarchar(255), 
        Headline nvarchar(80), 
        Slug nvarchar(100), 
        StatusId int, 
        PrimaryImage nvarchar (300)  
    )

    INSERT INTO #T1 
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL_QUERY,  N'@INDEX int, @PageSize int', @INDEX, @PageSize 

    SELECT Id
    FROM #T1
END
```

The issue is that I need this procedure to hit other tables besides the one it is hitting now (`Friends` table). The obvious blocker is that in my logic I'm stopped by the hard-coded table since I'm shoving the result of the `@SQL_QUERY` which WILL ALWAYS BE a selection of columns.

I only need to test for the Ids and I'm wondering if there's such a way to only get my Ids back with logic that is ignorant of the other columns.

The biggest thing is that I can't change the fact that I'm hitting another procedure that again, WILL ALWAYS return to me multiple columns because of the different tables it'll be hitting.

** More context
I've a few hundred other Databases that I'll be hitting that need to include a proc named "Friends_Pagination" that returns a paginated list of friends. There are other tables such as Users or Skills or Images that I need to test for pagination. I only want to test for the returned Ids and nothing else. However, I must run their stored proc. Consequently, their stored proc returns more than just a list of Ids. I only need that list of Ids rather than accepting all of their data then filtering over the Id columns ... I'm wondering if I could just accept the Ids.

Comment: I have to admit I don't understand what you are trying to do. Maybe you can add sample data or an example to clarify.

Comment: Is there some reason Friends_Pagination is a stored procedure instead of a view or a table-valued function? Is it modifying data?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I've a few hundred other Databases that I'll be hitting that need to include a proc named "Friends_Pagination" that returns a paginated list of friends. There are other tables such as Users or Skills or Images that I need to test for pagination. I only want to test for the returned Ids and nothing else. However, I must run their stored proc. Consequently, their stored proc returns more than just a list of Ids